# Is an enum with string (quoted text) in Typescript possible?

Tags: typescript, enums

I do not know typescript and I have not found any information anywhere, is such a construction possible?

```
export enum Something {
    'qwe' = 1,
    'rty' = 2,
    'uio' = 3,
}
```

Comment: You can use computed property names for this: `['qwe'] = 1, ['rty'] = 2, ['uio'] = 3,`. But this is exactly the same as `qwe = 1, rty = 2, uio = 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have an enum, just drop the quotes.

```
enum Something {
  qwe = 1,
  rty = 2,
  uio = 3,
}
```

If you want to use literal strings, you can just declare a `type`

```
type Something = 'qwe' | 'rty' | 'uio';
```

If you want the strings *and* their associations to integers, you can declare an object and then use `keyof`.

```
const Something = {
  qwe: 1,
  rty: 2,
  uio: 3,
}

type Something = keyof typeof Something;
```

This uses [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), so the two `Something` names we declare are in distinct namespaces. The *type* `Something` is defined in terms of the *value* `Something`.

Now `Something` is a type whose value is any string key in the value `Something`, and we can write `Something[x]` to convert a value of that type (again, a string) into the corresponding number.

If you're writing new Typescript code, I recommend just going with the `enum` and dropping the quotation marks; it's what `enum` is for. But if you have an existing code base that already does it with strings, then the latter approaches can be useful.